# Built a model using Keras that reports good accuracy, but then can't get predict to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, predict

I have built a neural network model using Keras/Tensorflow, that reports good training and validation accuracy (90%-ish) when built (using 'fit_generator') and reports similar accuracy using the 'evaluate_generator' function on the test set. But when I then try to use the model to generate predictions, either using 'predict_generator' or manually for individual files, it gives an answer of '0' for every prediction. Code below. I am quite inexperienced, and would really appreciate guidance. Thanks.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img, ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import load_model
import glob, sys
import numpy as np

myModel = load_model("Gender.h5")
dataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator()
testGen = dataGenerator.flow_from_directory("newData\\A1\\test",target_size=(218,178),
    batch_size=32, class_mode='binary',shuffle=False,color_mode="rgb")
testGen.reset()
print("Test Set Accuracy: %0.1f%%"%(100*myModel.evaluate_generator(testGen)[1]))
testGen.reset()
testPredictions = myModel.predict_generator(testGen)
predictedClassIndices=np.argmax(testPredictions,axis=1)
filenames = testGen.filenames
for f in range(len(filenames)):
    print(filenames[f],":",predictedClassIndices[f])
```

Comment: post the `myModel.summary()` result.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility of this scenario is that your Classes might be `Imbalanced`.  If that is the case, you can try:

- Rebalance your dataset: by either upsampling the less frequent class or downsampling the more frequent one.
- Adjust class weights: by setting the higher class weight for less frequent class you'll be promoting your network training for putting more attention on the downsampled class.
- Increase the time of training: in many cases - after longer period of training time network starts concentrating more on less frequent classes.

Other Possbility => If your `Dataset` is **Balanced**, then, the problem here is in the **final step** when you are assigning class to the `testPredictions` outcome. The `argmax` method returns `the indices of the maximum values along an axis`.

In this case, it's always **0** because along `axis=1` we have only one element (`with index 0`).

Since you're performing `binary classification`, it makes most sense to apply `0.5` `probability threshold` to assign `classes`. Code for the same is shown below:

```
predictedClassIndices = testPredictions > 0.5

for idx, filename in enumerate(filenames):
    print(filename,":",predictedClassIndices[idx])
```

Then the Output will be `True` and `False`, with **False** representing `Value of Label = 0 (Female)` and **True** representing `Value of Label = 1 (Male)` or can be other way, as shown below:

```
female/female.1546.jpg : [False]
female/female.1547.jpg : [ True]
female/female.1548.jpg : [False]
female/female.1549.jpg : [False]
female/female.1550.jpg : [False]
female/female.1566.jpg : [False]
female/female.1593.jpg : [ True]
female/female.1594.jpg : [False]
male/male.1514.jpg : [ True]
male/male.1520.jpg : [False]
male/male.1525.jpg : [False]
male/male.1551.jpg : [ True]
male/male.1555.jpg : [False]
male/male.1574.jpg : [ True]
male/male.1594.jpg : [ True]
male/male.1597.jpg : [ True]
male/male.1599.jpg : [ True]
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that scaling is missing where you get the zero.
Try to test this doing `myModel.predict(data)`, where data is the image array. If you did not apply scaling to the image array, you may get zeroes as outcomes. If you do `myModel.predict(data/255)`,
you should get what you originally had,  using `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)`, where the scaling is set as a parameter.

Please let me know if you resolved this, apologies that I am late to this game :-)